# run time error '6' Overflow in visual basic 6.0

Tags: vb6

I am getting a run time error '6' Over Flow in vb 6 [image]

Comment: Well that's a long number that won't fit into a `Long`. Try `Double`, `Currency` or `String`.

Comment: The image is too small to read

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "Overflow" error means that you are trying to put a number into a variable (or property etc), and the data type of the variable doesn't allow numbers that large.

Make sure that numbers used in calculations that are coerced into integers do not have results larger than integers.

Answer (score 1):

What is the type of the data in the database?

My guess is that ADO returns it as either a String or a Decimal, and Decimal values only "fit into" a Variant in VB6.

VB6 has no syntax for a Decimal literal, however you can use something like:

```
CDec(111010114289@)
```

... inline, or declare a Const as in:

```
Private Const BigVal As Currency = 111010114289@
```

Comment: yes it was a String in DB, now I convert this value using to_number(****) in my sql and also used DOUBLE datatype in VB6

Comment: If it is a String then it seems unlikely that arithmetic upon it makes any sense.  Double is an imprecise datatype by nature and should be used with extreme caution.  Currency and Decimal are scaled integers.  You need to ask yourself what you are doing to decide whether to keep a String a String or choose a numeric type, and if so which one.

Answer (score 0):

I you have to put a large number in a small variable, like C, check Remove integer bound check in project properties  (if you are not compiling as PCode)

Comment: I need to store a 12 digit number. what type of datatype I should use in VB6

Comment: Heres you answer : [How to emulate .net Int64 in VB6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20885338/how-to-emulate-net-int64-in-vb6/20885339#20885339)